# django python функция reverse

Tags: python, django

При импорте из библиотеки django.core.urlresolvers функции reverse, в терминале ошибка что нет такой библиотеки. Версия django 2.1.1.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что уже несколько версий как функция `reverse` располагается в пакете `django.urls`. Читайте свежую документацию.